# Role based Authorization Django/Graphql/Apollo/Vue

Tags: django, vue.js, graphql, apollo, graphene-python

I am working on a project that uses Django as the backend with graphql/graphene as an api and Vue Js and apollo client for the front end. I am lost as to how I can implement role based authorization using this set up. I am wondering if a can using Django's base auth package or can I get DRF authorization to work with this? I know that graphene has support for authorization using relay, can I make this work with apollo in the front end? Or is a better idea to use some package such as vue-kindergarden to keep all the authorization in the vue js front end? Keeping all the authorization in the front end seems somewhat sketchy to me. Has anyone had an experience with this or have some input on what the best option is?

Answer (score 1):

In the same boat as yours. My current site uses cookies. As I am now planning to integrate Vue, I have to rethink auth and this is what I found as a good starting point for me. I knew about JWTs earlier, but this post helps bring it out in a clear manner. https://stormpath.com/blog/token-auth-spa and https://jwt.io.

While I haven't checked what the libraries which you have mentioned do but don't keep everything in the frontend.